# scratchpad.io functions don't work

Tags: javascript, scratchpad

I am trying to use functions on the website [scratchpad.io](http://scratchpad.io/functions), but they don't appear to work. I have tried using onclick events for buttons and just having it call the function from inside of the same script tag after it is defined. Does anyone know why this is, and how to fix it?

```
<script>
function Message(){
alert("scratchpad.io does not work with functions... You won't see this!");
console.log("scratchpad.io does not work with functions... You won't see this!");
}
Message();
</script>
<br>
<button onclick="Message();">Trigger Function</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

scratchpad.io is for HTML & CSS, it does not support javascript. For that you can use one of the many other similar services that exist out there, like:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/?html,output)

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/)